# How to get the maximum value from an ArrayList

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get highest price of a product. I'm able to store the prices in an object.
I want to know how to get the maximum value from that object. Below is my code!

```
public class amazon {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("xyzzz.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        amazon az = new amazon();
        az.run();

        }

    public void run() throws Exception {


            List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();

            List<WebElement> tag = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));

            int i;
            for(i=0; i<tag.size(); i++) {

                obj.add(tag.get(i).getText());

            }

            System.out.println(obj);
            driver.close();

    }
```

Output i have..

```
[64,900, 99,900, 1,23,900, 64,900, 64,900, 69,900, 64,900, 64,900, 1,23,900, 52,900]
```

Comment: How much is `1,23,900`?

Comment: In any case, what issues are you having making the strings into numbers? Then tracking the highest value as you add to the second list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the numbers to int, and than you can use `Collections.max` on the list

```
List<Integer> prices = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> tags = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));
for (WebElement tag: tags) {
    prices.add(Integer.parseInt(tag.getText().replace(",", "")));
}
System.out.print(Collections.max(prices)); // 123900
```

Comment: No need to create a separate list, if only looking for the max

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked! I need to learn more about collections it seems!

Answer (score 3):

Map the strings to ints (or longs, or some type of currency), then you can get the max using a Comparator

```
int max = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']")).stream() 
    .map(WebElement::getText)
    .map(s -> s.replace(",", ""))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .max(Integer::compare)
    .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

create an int and call it max (=0), run on each element of the list using a loop (for loop recommended), on each element, check if its bigger than max, if yes, put the value in max,
here is a little code, in case the list is called "list", change it to whatever you want

```
int max=0;
for (int i : list){
  if (i >max)
    max=i;
}
System.out.println(max) //print the maximum value of the array
```

Comment: if it's about product prices, it is easier to work with an array of integers, and do whatever u want with each element

Comment: The question already has a list. Arrays don't make it any easier to get the max. Especially if using the Stream api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: In case nothing else is working for him, he can use this and run the code